# Remove Reset button on jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

jqgrid has the search form, this form has 2 buttons "Reset" and "Find", I need to remove the "Reset" button, Is this posible? what is the way?.
I has the last version of jqgrid.
Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I am going to vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably just hide it by adding this to your css.

```
a#fbox_grps_reset {
    display: none;
}
```